# C# Regex - Заменить все пробелы, кроме тех которые в кавычках

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо заменить все пробелы которые есть в тексте, кроме тех, которые находятся в кавычках ' и "

Найти все пробелы или весь текст в кавычках я могу, а вот как это совместить, я пока понять не могу.

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"("".*?"")|('.*?')|\s+", ",");
```

Пробовал и убрать "захват" в группу через (?:), но не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `Regex.Replace(text,@"\s+(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)");`

Comment: VisualStudio не принимает, ошибки пишет.

Comment: @F1nKe Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: Ошибка CS1010 Символ новой строки в константе
Ошибка CS1525 Недопустимый термин "" в выражении
Ошибка CS1056 Недопустимый символ "$"
Ошибка CS0193 К указателю должен быть применен оператор * или ->.

Comment: @F1nKe А если так?
`string s = "\\s+(?=([^\"]* \"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)";
            Regex.Replace("text", s);`

Comment: Ошибок нет, но и пробелы не заменяются.